# Updating a view in backbone when a collection is updated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a web app that I am building, I have form input that allows you to enter a name, on entering this name, I want to update a list with that inputted name, my problem is however that if add one name and then another the previos name that is outputted to the view, is overwritten (but if I refresh the page I get the full list). Here is my code,

```
GroupModalHeaderView.prototype.render = function() {
  this.$el.empty();
  if (this.model.isNew()) {
    this.$el.append(this.template({
      m: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
    return this.edit();
  } else {
    this.$el.append(this.template({
      m: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
    this.$el.find(".modal-header-menu").show();
    return this.$el.find(".icon-button-close-modal").show();
  }
};



GroupModalHeaderView.prototype.save = function(e) {
      var $collection, $this;
      if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $this = this;
      if (this.$("#group-name").val() !== "") {
        $collection = this.collection;
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
          this.collection.push(this.model);
        }
        return this.model.save({
          name: this.$("#group-name").val(),
          async: false,
          wait: true
        }, {
          success: function() {
            return $this.cancel();
          }
        });
      }
    };

GroupListView.prototype.events = {
      "click .list-header-add": "add",
      "click .list-header-expander": "showHide",
      "keyup #search-query": "keyup"
    };

    GroupListView.prototype.initialize = function() {
      //console.log("fired");
      this.collection.on("change", this.renderList, this);
      this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
      return this.renderList();
    };

GroupListView.prototype.renderList = function(collection) {
      var responsiveHeight = $("body").height() - 400;
      if($("#people-network-requests").is(":visible")) {
        this.$el.find("#people-groups-list").height($("#people-people-list").height()-250+"px");
      } else {
        this.$el.find("#people-groups-list").height($("#people-people-list").height()+"px");
      }
      var $collection, $this;
      if (!collection) {
        collection = this.collection;
      }
      this.$el.find(".list-items").empty();
      $this = this.$el.find("#people-groups-list");
      this.$el.find(".list-items").removeClass("list-items-loading").empty();
      $collection = collection;
      if ($collection.length < 1) {
        /*this.$el.find("#people-groups-inner").hide();
        $(".activity-no-show").remove();
        return this.$el.find("#people-groups-inner").append('<div class="activity-no-show">\
        <p>To add a new group, click the + in the top right hand corner to get started.</p>\
        </div>');*/
      } else {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
          var displayView;
          displayView = new app.GroupListDisplayView({
            model: item,
            collection: $collection
          });
          console.log($this);
          return $this.append(displayView.render());
        });
        return this;
      }
    };

    return GroupListView;

  })(app.BaseView);

GroupListDisplayView.prototype.render = function() {
      //console.log(this.$el);
      //alert("1");
      var $body;
      this.$el.html(this.template({
        m: this.model.toJSON()
      }));
      $body = this.$el.find(".card-body");
      $text = $body.text();
      $.each(this.model.get("people"), function(i, person) {
        var personTile;
        this.person = new app.Person({
          id: person.id,
          avatar: person.avatar,
          first_name: person.first_name,
          last_name: person.last_name
        });
        personTile = new app.PersonTileView({
          model: this.person
        });
        if(person.id) { 
          $body.append(personTile.render()).find(".instruction").remove();
        }
      });
      return this.$el.attr("id", "group-card-" + this.model.id);
    };

GroupListView.prototype.keyup = function() {
      this.filtered = $collection.searchName(this.$el.find("#search-query").val());
      //console.log(this.filtered);
      return this.renderList(this.filtered);
    };
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using prototype instead of Backbone.View.extend?

Comment: inherited code, project is not at point to refactor at the moment, so I am stuck with what a previos dev as done for the time being

Answer (score 0):

```
this.collection.on("add", this.addDisplayView, this);
```

Then create a function `addDisplayView` that accepts the model for the view. You will need to refactor the `this.collection.each(function(item)...` part of your code to use the `addDisplayView` function.

```
GroupListView.prototype.addDisplayView = function(model){
    var displayView = new app.GroupListDisplayView({
        model: model,
        collection: this.collection
    });
    // use this.$, as it is already mapped to the context of the view
    return this.$("#people-groups-list").append(displayView.render());
}
```

You should also change `this.collection.push(this.model);` to `this.collection.add(this.model);`

> **addcollection.add(models, [options])**
>
> Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection, firing an "add" event. If a model property
> is defined, you may also pass raw attributes objects, and have them be
> vivified as instances of the model. Pass {at: index} to splice the
> model into the collection at the specified index. If you're adding
> models to the collection that are already in the collection, they'll
> be ignored, unless you pass {merge: true}, in which case their
> attributes will be merged into the corresponding models, firing any
> appropriate "change" events.
>
> http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-add

Comment: what does the addDisplayView actually do - I already have a function that builds the view

Comment: GroupListView.prototype.addDisplayView would be used to create the DisplayView. I will mock something up.

Comment: Thanks - I run this when a collection is added too, but it still overwrites the last entered name until I refresh the page, it almost like the I am adding to one collection then reading from another completely different one.

Comment: Right it looks like that if I add a futher name after adding the first, this.collection.on("change") or this.collection.on("add" are not firing) is this possible? Why would this.collection.on not fire?

Comment: I'm looking through the code... I feel for you man. Do you have a fiddle or something to demonstrate it? I think your problem is that you are using this.collection.push(this.model); Change it to this.collection.add(this.model);

Comment: I try get a fiddle together at somepoint this evening. Strange this, changed to .add still overwrites, but I now get a console error, Uncaught ReferenceError: $collection is not defined it complains about line 55 which I have added to the code in my OP.

Comment: try this.collection instead of $collection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32766/discussion-between-sico87-and-moderndegree)

Comment: and this.$el.find("#search-query").val() is unnecessary. You can just do this.$("#search-query").val(). view.$ is a scoped query.